# How to deploy to azure app service from VSTS?

Tags: node.js, git, azure, deployment, azure-pipelines

I have nodejs app. Can I deploy it to azure app service without VS or other big IDE?

So, I want an easy way to select branch what I need push it to azure and run default command for nodejs.

I'm stuck with it, because all of solution it is use VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy to azure app service by using Azure App Service Deployment step/task. For example:

1. Create a build definition
2. Add related step/task to build your project
3. Add Azure App Service Deployment step/task (Can publish using Web Deploy or upload files directly)
4. Select Triggers tab and enable Continuous Integration
5. Specify repository and branch filters

After that, the build will be triggered if you push changes to target branch.
Related article: [Define a continuous integration build for your Node.js app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/node/nodejs-to-azure)

Regarding run command for nodejs, you can refer to this thread by using kudu API: [Include node modules in azure deployment via VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897305/include-node-modules-in-azure-deployment-via-vsts/43906788#43906788).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. Take a look at the build and release functionality in Visual Studio Team Services.

With VSTS Build, you can trigger a build and push to an Azure Web App automatically on a Git check-in for a particular branch, or you can manually trigger the build and push.

Take a look at the Azure App Service Deploy task in VSTS build.

Note that since VSTS is pulling from your Git repo, it doesn't matter what IDE you use to actually develop your app with.

Also, VSTS is free for small teams and a single deployment pipeline.